# bash: IFS not honoured by read command

Tags: bash, read

From the bash man page for the `read` command:

> One line is read from the standard input, or from the file descriptor  fd  supplied as an argument to the -u option, split into words as described above under Word Splitting,  and  the  first  word  is assigned to the first name,...

Now I tried out the following:

```
IFS=,
echo ' a b,c d'|read -n 4 x y
echo ".$x. .$y."
```

I expected the output to be

```
. a b. .c d.
```

becaus due to the change, word splitting should occur at the comma instead of the space, but the actual output was

```
.a. ..
```

This puzzles me. The `.a.` looks like word splitting is still done at spaces, but then at least, `y` should be set to `b`, not being empty.

I can't help but feeling that I misunderstand the explanations in the man-page about the `read` command.

BTW, I'm using bash 4.4.12.

Comment: Any values you're seeing are not from the `read`.

Answer (score 4):

It works just fine:

```
$ IFS=,; echo ' a b,c d' | { read x y; declare -p x y;}
declare -- x=" a b"
declare -- y="c d"
```

#### Notes

1. Because it is in a pipeline, the `read` statement is in a subshell.  The variables `x` and `y` are limited in scope to that subshell.  In the above, we added curly braces so that the `declare` statement was in the same subshell as the `read` statement.  That way, the declare output shows the values of x and y that were read.

   If we remove the curly braces, then the `declare` statement is no longer in the same subshell and the values of `x` and `y` are not preserved.  Observe:

   ```
   $ x=hot; y=cold; IFS=,; echo ' a b,c d' | read -n 4 x y; declare -p x y
   declare -- x="hot"
   declare -- y="cold"
   ```
2. To avoid the subshell limit, we can use a here-string:

   ```
   $ IFS=,; read x y <<<' a b,c d'; declare -p x y
   declare -- x=" a b"
   declare -- y="c d"
   ```

   With a here-string, the `read` statement is in the main shell and the values of `x` and `y` are not lost.
3. `-n 4` limits `read` to 4 characters. That probably is not what you wanted.  Observe:

   ```
   $ IFS=,; echo ' a b,c d' | { read -n 4 x y; declare -p x y;}
   declare -- x=" a b"
   declare -- y=""
   ```

   Here,  `x` takes up all 4 characters (blanks do count as characters), there are no characters read for `y`.
4. As [PesaThe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/186569/pesathe), it is also possible to assign shell variables locally just for the execution of one command.  Because changes to IFS might cause unwanted side-effects in subsequent commands, that is a good idea here.  Thus:

   ```
   $ IFS=, read x y <<<' a b,c d'; declare -p x y
   declare -- x=" a b"
   declare -- y="c d"
   ```

   After the above command is run, `IFS` is returned to its previous value.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `IFS` can be declared just for `read`.

Comment: @PesaThe Excellent suggestion!  Answer updated with local variable assignment.